# How to Recognize a Battery's Technology

Tags: batteries, identification, battery-chemistry

Given a battery of unknown chemistry and unknown origin, how to I tell it's a rechargeable alkaline manganese, NiMH or NiCd battery by looking at its electrical or physical properties, eg. maybe they have a different distinct capacity-weight-ratio or significantly different discharge or charge behavior. Taking them apart is not an option. I'm not sure if this might be better on the chemistry SE.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechargeable_alkaline_battery

Comment: I've expanded the acronym for that one, as "RAM" is usually used to refer to something entirely different (that is, memory).

Comment: *maybe they have a different distinct capacity-weight-ratio* Sure but what about the weight of the case around it. So you cannot know the weight of the battery itself. If you do not know the battery's chemistry you cannot determine the capacity as you do not know to what voltage to charge/discharge it. In short: **you can only be sure if it is printed on the battery**

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, but very different wording.